# How to change colour of delegate component on map in qt qml

Tags: qt, qml, maps, qqmlcomponent

I am  using MapQuickItem as a delegate component on map. I have three component. I want to chnage the colour of delegate component when I am clicking on component.And rest are as same colour.How to change the colour of only selected component colour

```
 Plugin
{
    id: hereMaps
    name: "here"
    PluginParameter { name: "here.app_id"; value: "oBB4FivcP23m2UZQCj8K" }
    PluginParameter { name: "here.token"; value: "P-D8XRRGeVt0YphUuOImeA" }
}

Map {
    id: map
    anchors.fill: parent
    activeMapType: supportedMapTypes[1];
    zoomLevel: 18
    plugin: hereMaps
    center: QtPositioning.coordinate(19.997454, 73.789803)

    MapItemView {
        id: markerItem
        model: [
            { id: "marker1", color: "red" },
            { id: "marker2", color: "red" },
            { id: "marker3", color: "red" }
        ]
        delegate: mapMarkerComponent
    }

    Component {
        id : mapMarkerComponent

        MapQuickItem {
            id: mapMarker
            coordinate: QtPositioning.coordinate(19.997454, 73.789803)

            sourceItem: Rectangle {

                id: handle
                color: modelData.color
                width: 40
                height: 40

                MouseArea {
                    drag.target: parent
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onClicked: {

                        handle.color = "green"

                    }
                }
            }

            onCoordinateChanged: {
                console.log(modelData.id + ":" + coordinate);
            }
        }
    }
   }
```

Comment: This code already do that: changes colour of clicked marker from red to green... Be more precise. What you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to change colour of that rectangle component when I will click on that. There are three rectangle components in my code. When I click on first rectangle it becomes green and other two are red. When I am clicking on second rectangle I want to change the colour of second rectangle and first and third becomes red. But in my code when I click on second rectangle first is also remains green.How to make first and third rectangle red and only clicked rectangle to  red

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most obvious approach is to iterate through all markers and reset colours of those, then change colour of clicked marker. To do this, change `onClicked` to:

```
// switch to red if its green
if (handle.color == "#008000") {
    handle.color = "#ff0000";
    return;
}
// switch all markers to red
for(var marker in markerItem.children) {
    markerItem.children[marker].sourceItem.color = "#ff0000";
}
// switch clicked marker to green
handle.color = "#008000";
```

However, this is not the best solution (manipulate on colours), if you want to "select" marker. Read about states in QML ([link](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-state.html)), and try to implement some kind of "normal" and "selected" state to your markers.

Comment: got the solution! Thank you!!